# Broken grub on kali linux partition

Tags: kali-linux, grub

Hey I use to have kali and windows working together this way:
Windows was booting in priority
I could press <kbd>F11</kbd> and choose to on sdb5 and Kali was running.

I had broke my Kali install and had to reinstall it at the same place.
During the installation I choose not to install grub because I wanted the same behavior.

When I boot I've got Windows as default (as wanted) but when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> and choose to boot on sdb5 I've got an error and end-up in grub-rescue.

I tried to do the following (in grub rescue mode) to fix it but it didn't work (same error):

```
set root=(hd1,sda5)
set prefix=(hd1,sda5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

So I tried to boot on a Kali live CD and did:

```
$ sudo grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/media/root/fc3098f2-bc4e-490a-9503-4cb069ff3227 /dev/sdb5
```

It didn't work either I've got the error:

> The file /media/root/fc3098f2-bc4e-490a-9503-4cb069ff3227/boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.

The issue might comes from the fact that I didn't install grub at installation and that I still have my old grub (?)

I don't know what to do to be able to boot on kali as I was doing before, can you help me?

*More infos:*

Here is the state of my sdb disk, sdb5 is my kali partition, windows is on sda:[image]

`$ fsdik -l`  gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7804DE5E-CFA4-40E9-BE9D-6A2FDA4FE8C6

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 3907028991 3906764800  1.8T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5BD63C37-E942-4B29-A8AE-B37A718A214D

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048     264191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2      264192  929523711 929259520 443.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3   929523712 1748723711 819200000 390.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  1748723712 1748725759      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb5  1748725760 1936895999 188170240  89.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb6  1936896000 1953523711  16627712     8G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1063C98C-6F88-4F38-B945-B0C59D49DCF0

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    616447    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     616448    819199    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3     819200   1081343    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1081344 233519103 232437760 110.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  233519104 234440703    921600   450M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdd: 7.2 GiB, 7747397632 bytes, 15131636 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x008e5725

Device     Boot   Start      End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *       2048  7342079 7340032  3.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdd2       7342080 15116287 7774208  3.7G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/loop0: 2.5 GiB, 2634285056 bytes, 5145088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

(I'm struggling with grub stuff, tell me if you need more info on the state of my system)

Comment: The set root commands should have worked. What is the error when you boot kali?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to repair my Grub following this answer in the end in case anyone have the same issue:

After booting from a kali linux live cd. I opened gparted to find that sdb5 was the partition where kali was installed. 
Then I typed the following commands:

```
$ mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt
$ mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
$ mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$ chroot /mnt
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
$ update-grub
$ exit
$ umount /mnt/dev/pts
$ umount /mnt/dev
$ umount /mnt/proc
$ umount /mnt/sys
$ umount /mnt
```

This have restored the old kali linux boot loader on the partition so I can boot on it again by pressing f11 at boot (if you want a real grub follow link for more details)

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7